# Does $| E[X*1\{X<\mu\}] | = | E[X*1\{X>\mu\}] |$?

Tags: probability-distributions, exponentiation

Does mean of a random variable $\mu=E[X]$ devide conditional mean in half, in a sense that

$$ | E]X*1\{X<\mu\}] | = | E[X*1\{X>\mu\}]  |$$

or is this only true for symmetric distributions?

Answer (score 1):

Not true in general. Let $X$ take values $1$ and $2$ with ptobabilites $\frac 1 3$ and  $\frac 2 3$. Then EX=$\frac 5 3$,  LHS is $\frac 1 3$  and RHS is $\frac 4 3$

Answer (score 1):

This is not even true for symmetric distributions. Suppose that $P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2$. Then
$$
\operatorname E[X1\{X<0\}]=-\frac12
$$
but
$$
\operatorname E[X1\{X>0\}]=\frac12.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to apply the absolute to the expectations on both sides of the mean. But thank you for your reply in any case.